# How to get the GuzzleHttp client to propperly send POST requests?

Tags: php, rest, post, guzzle

According to the documentation of GuzzleHttp/Guzzle v7 (https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#sending-form-fields), there should be the option to send a regular POST request to an URL (e.g. http://localhost/form.php) by using both functions ...

So my `form.php` looks like that:

```php
<?php
var_dump([
    'REQUEST' => $_REQUEST,
    'GET'     => $_GET,
    'POST'    => $_POST,
]);
```

and the Guzzle-Code like that:

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://localhost',
]);

$r1 = $client->post( '/form.php', [
    'json' => [
        'lorem' => 'ipsum',
    ]
]);

echo $r1->getBody()->getContents() . "\n\n============\n\n";

$r2 = $client->request( 'POST', '/form.php', [
    'json' => [
        'lorem' => 'ipsum',
    ]
]);

echo $r2->getBody()->getContents();
```

... The result of running the guzzle code shows this:

```
array(3) {
  ["REQUEST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["GET"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["POST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}


============

array(3) {
  ["REQUEST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["GET"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["POST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

What am I missing / messing up with? ...

A request within the browser to `http://localhost/form.php?asdf` results in the (correct) response:

```
array(3) {
  ["REQUEST"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["asdf"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["GET"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["asdf"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["POST"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the issue could be that you send the data with the `'json'` key. Try adding it as `'body'` instead and see if that works better: `'body' => ['lorem' => 'ipsum]`. If you want to post it as JSON, then you might need to get the data in your form.php like this: `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` and then [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) that string.

Comment: Please check the docs you linked in your question: _"Sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST requests requires that you specify the POST fields as an array in the `form_params` request options."_ This adds up to what @MagnusEriksson wrote, the `json` option is for JSON and `form_params` is so that the `$_POST` superglobal is being filled. for `$_GET` you need to add `?asdf` to the URL string of the request if you want to have it comparable to the "(correct)" response. - compare as well with the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php